# OnParametersSetAsync create infinite loop

Tags: blazor, razor-components

At first, the logic to get the data for the child component was inside the **OnInitializedAsync** method but I realised that if the dropdown changed, the child component wasn't updated. Basically, depending on the category selected, I query different data from the database.

Here the code:

```
<EditForm Model="Model" OnValidSubmit="Save">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Category">Category</label>
        <select id="Category" class="custom-select" @onchange="OnCategoryChanged">
            <option value=""></option>
            @foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
            {
                if (Model.Category != null && Model.Category.Value == category.Id)
                {
                    <option value="@category.Id" selected="selected">@category.Name</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@category.Id">@category.Name</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Category)" />
    </div>

    @if (Model.Category != null && Model.Category.IsExternalOrNonRuning == false)
    {
        <ChildComponent @bind-Data="Model.Data" Id="Id" Category="Model.Category" />
    }
</EditForm>
```

The code for this component

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Model = _Query(Id);
}

private void OnCategoryChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
   Model.Category = e.Value.ToString();
}
```

I decided to move my code from **OnInitializedAsync** to **OnParametersSetAsync** so every time the dropdown changes, the child component is updated. However, this create an infinite loop. The method is called continuously even though the parameters haven't been updated.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Try moving code back to init and every time dropdown changes, call statehaschanged.

Comment: Do what @KrishnaDhungana said.

Comment: @Tyler Durden, e.Value.ToString() in the OnCategoryChanged method is evaluated to category.Id in <option value="@category.Id" ... Once again, what is Model.Category. You've already have Model.Categories, so what is  Model.Category. Please, post complete code, including your model classes.